# Sort a PHP array keys matching specific texts

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays.

First array contains search keywords:

```
$search=Array ( [0] => iphone [1] => grey )
```

Second array contains some key values pair like below.

```
$required_data=Array ( 
           'iphonewhite' => "val1",
           'iphonesilver' => "val1",
           'iphonegrey' => "val1",
           'iphonegrey silver' => "val1",
           'iphonesilverwhiterose' => "val1",

)
```

I need to sort the second array based on first array search keywords. i.e If key has all the keywords first array has should come first.

Expected Output is:

```
$data=Array ( 
           'iphonegrey' => "val1",
           'iphonegrey silver' => "val1",
           'iphonewhite' => "val1",
           'iphonesilver' => "val1",
           'iphonesilverwhiterose' => "val1",
)
```

I have below Idea to do this.

1. Loop the second array.
2. match the key string with first array values (another loop of first array to get all the values need to put inside)
3. If second array key contain all values of the first array then keep it in a first position or insert in a new array may be.
4. Return the new array.

Is there any other way?

Comment: It's not really clear on which property you want to sort this array

Comment: It's just sort by name? Just check PHP's [`arsort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php)

Comment: @rakwaht as simple can say. I want exact match with iphone & grey at first then other matches.

Comment: what you have done so far?

Comment: @AdhanTimothyYounes I have last option as to create new array using foreach loop & with string match from other array & put the data as per my requirement. I am looking for better option. If you have any idea please give. Anyways nothing is impossible in PHP can be managed that i know & hope you also know.

Comment: The question title says "sort" but the expected output has less entries than the input. Sorting doesn't modify the data in array, it just places the items in a different order.

Comment: can you post what did you try so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$search=array ( 0 => 'iphone', 1 => 'grey' ); 

$required_data=array ( 
           'iphonewhite' => "val1",
           'iphonesilver' => "val1",
           'iphonegrey' => "val1",
           'iphonegrey silver' => "val1",
           'iphonesilverwhiterose' => "val1",

);
$searchStr = implode('', $search);  //get the search string
$matchArray = array();
$notMatchArray = array();
foreach($required_data as $key=>$val){
    if(strpos($key, $searchStr) === false){ //find search string if it exist in array key or not
        $notMatchArray[$key] = $val;
    }else{
        $matchArray[$key] = $val;

    }
}

echo 'Final array';
print_r(array_merge($matchArray, $notMatchArray)); //merge two array
```

[Code snippet](https://3v4l.org/OGYet)